# CDialog update input box value

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I am working with CDialogs and mfc. My dialog loads, and there are two input boxes and a button. When i click the button I want to have the values in the input boxes change. My current attempt is this

```
void
CInstanceNumberDlg::updateLeftRange(int i) {
GetDlgItem(IDC_2NDDERIV_WT)->SetWindowText((LPCTSTR)i);
UpdateData(false);
UpdateWindow();
}
```

I have also tried with other combinations of including UpdateData() and UpdateWindow(). This method is being reached with a valid integer, and that ID should be valid.

How can i get the value in the input box to be modified?

Thank you

Comment: SetWindowText requires text. It is not valid to cast an int into text. Try creating a string (CString in MFC) from your integer and pass the string to SetWindowText.

Comment: You can also try `SetDlgItemInt(IDC_2NDDERIV_WT, i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_2NDDERIV_WT)->SetWindowText((LPCTSTR)i);
```

`i` is not a pointer to a string and so you should not be casting it to an `LPCTSTR`. What you need to do convert the value of `i` to a string and then pass a pointer to the resulting string to `SetWindowText()`. And I don't believe you need `UpdateData()` or `UpdateWindow()`. For example:

```
void CInstanceNumberDlg::updateLeftRange(int i)
{
  TCHAR tszValue[32];

  StringCchPrintf(tszValue, _countof(tszValue), TEXT("%d"), i);
  GetDlgItem(IDC_2NDDERIV_WT)->SetWindowText(tszValue);
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using StringCchPrintF over sprintf?

Comment: @pasquers: The differences between [StringCchPrintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647541.aspx) and the printf-family of functions is explained in the *Remarks* section.